# Wrong directory in passwd file. How to edit properly?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, passwd

I have the following value under /etc/passwd file:

```
web3:x:5006:5006::/var/www/clients/client2/web3:/bin/false
```

Now, the correct value should be:

```
web3:x:5006:5006::/var/www/clients/client1/web3:/bin/false
```

That is, client1 and not client2.

I know that it's not advisable to edit the passwd file directly using vi or other text editor. I learned that it should be edited using this command `vipw -s`. But when I run `vipw -s`, I cannot find this line `/var/www/clients/client1/web3:/bin/false`. What I can see is this `web3:!:15869:0:99999:7:::`.

So how can I change the value from client2 to client1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:
`usermod -d /var/www/clients/client1/web3 web3` or just `vipw` without -s.

Comment: Explanatory hint: The `-s` option for `vipw` changes the shadow file. This doesn't contain the home dir informations.